# Header image and footer line numbers in RMarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown

````
---
title: "An analysis of `r nrow(mtcars)` cars"
---
The title ends up above the header image. 
```{r echo=FALSE, out.width='100%'}
knitr::include_graphics('D:/Users/james/ui.png')
```
````

I have gone through many documents and am still not able to find a solution. The footer needs caption on the left side and a page number on the right side. But not sure on how to generate automatically the page numbers. I am very new to this rmarkdown and need some help figuring it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put any HTML tag including the image in the title itself:

## HTML

```
---
title: "<img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/SIPI_Jelly_Beans_4.1.07.tiff/lossy-page1-256px-SIPI_Jelly_Beans_4.1.07.tiff.jpg'><br>Title"
output: html_document
---

<style>
body {
  height: 100vh !important;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>

# An analysis

Lorem ipsum

<div class="footer">Footer</div>
```

[image]

## PDF

R-Markdown file:

```
---
title: ""
output:
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: "preamble.tex"
---

\thispagestyle{fancy}

![](SIPI_Jelly_Beans_4.1.07.tiff.jpg)

# Title

\lipsum
\lipsum
```

File `preamble.tex`:

```
\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
\fancyfoot[L]{Footer Caption}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}  % page number in "outer" position of footer line
```

[image]

Comment: Suppose there are 2 pages, will this image come as header for all the 2 pages ?

Comment: HTML is not paginated. Yo did not specify an output format. Do you want to create PDF or HTML?

Comment: I need the image to be a header for all the pages

Comment: The expected format is : header will be an image for all the pages and footer is page number on the right and caption on the left. I need it in pdf format

Comment: The *file* format will be pdf?

Comment: yes. in pdf and html document format. Certain places i need in html and others in pdf.

Comment: For now i need to know how to do it in pdf format

Comment: Can i know how to do page numbers for footer ?  I need a straight line above the footer with numbers on right @danlooo

Comment: I have attached a sample header and footer.

Comment: @james I revised my answer